# Convert javascript to jslib plugin for unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

since unity doesn't support microphone in webgl, i am trying to create a jslib that will do the work instead of the C# script ( i searched a lot in the unity forums and i think this may work, not sure though).
I found a javascript script that record audio and play it, but i tried to convert it to a jslib like unity manual said (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) but it doesnt work. I am pretty sure the problem is with async/wait ( i only know the basics of javascript).
It will be much appreciated if someone can help me solve the issue or give me a link to a tutorial that can help me ( i searched but i couldnt find anything helpful).
This is the javascript i found (it work when used with html):

```
const recordAudio = () =>
  new Promise(async resolve => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    const audioChunks = [];

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    const start = () => mediaRecorder.start();

    const stop = () =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
          const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
          const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
          const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
          const play = () => audio.play();
          resolve({ audioBlob, audioUrl, play });
        });

        mediaRecorder.stop();
      });

    resolve({ start, stop });
  });

let recorder = null;
let audio = null;

const recordStop = async () => {
  if (recorder) {
    audio = await recorder.stop();
    recorder = null;
  } else {
    recorder = await recordAudio();
    recorder.start();
  }
};

const playAudio = () => {
  if (audio && typeof audio.play === "function") {
    audio.play();
  }
};
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: @LeoBartkus thats the same link i posted

Comment: What is the error you are getting?   Can you post the javascript you ended up with after following the documentation?

Comment: Hi! Are you trying to use it in WebGL, right? And second question is : can You please show, how you try to call your recordAudio from c#?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work as a plugin callable from `c#` it needs to be added to the compiled JS library.

Somewhat like e.g.

```
const audioRecorder =
{
    $recorder : null,
    $audio : null,

    recordStop : async function() 
    {
        if (recorder) 
        {
            audio = await recorder.stop();
            recorder = null;
        }
        else 
        {
            const recordAudio = () =>
            {
                new Promise(async resolve => 
                {
                    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                    const audioChunks = [];

                   mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => 
                    {
                        audioChunks.push(event.data);
                    });

                    const start = () => mediaRecorder.start();

                    const stop = () => new Promise(resolve => 
                    {
                        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () =>
                        {
                            const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
                            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                            const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
                            const play = () => audio.play();
                            resolve({ audioBlob, audioUrl, play });
                    });

                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                });

                resolve({ start, stop });
            });

            recorder = await recordAudio();
            recorder.start();
        }
    },

    playAudio : function()
    {
        if (audio && typeof audio.play === "function") 
        {
            audio.play();
        }
    }
};

autoAddDeps(audioRecorder, '$recorder');
autoAddDeps(audioRecorder, '$audio');

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, audioRecorder);
```

And then on `c#` side

```csharp
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void recordAudio();

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void recordStop();

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void playAudio();
```

When building the WebGL app the compiler will then basically compile the jslib into the `Framework.js` file where again it would probably look similar to what you have now.